# Some social buttons sometimes not shown

Tags: facebook, wordpress, twitter, share

I'm adding social buttons for every post link in a web site where some post links are shown at once.
The problem is that sometimes some buttons are not shown and keep waiting for a response. I've tried with some browsers and computers and it's happening sometimes with any of them.

I'm adding the buttons like this:

```
<div class="social">
    <div class="twitter">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="_nofollow" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-lang="es" data-count="vertical">Twittear</a>
    </div>&nbsp
    <div class="facebook"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php the_permalink() ?>&amp;layout=box_count&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;locale=es_ES" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height:62px; width:74px" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>
    <g:plusone size="tall" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></g:plusone>
</div>
```

This is the web page: http://nosabesnada.com/ultimas-noticias/

Any idea of why it is sometimes happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Just checked it's working fine , i think it's either loading time slow for you .

Comment: @user3546239 - Well. It's just happening sometimes. Not always.

Comment: most likely iframe delays then it just halts , IMHO